# How to manipulate the current date?

Tags: mediawiki

Using MediaWiki we can acess current date with:

```
{{CURRENTYEAR}}-{{CURRENTMONTH}}-{{CURRENTDAY2}}
```

The output being:

```
2017-02-02
```

**However**, how could I manipulate the current date so I can **insert the previous month?**

I've tried `{{CURRENTYEAR-1}}` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [builtin magic words](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Date_and_time) don't allow for any manipulation, you can only insert the current date/time.

You'll need to install the [*Parser functions* extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) which lets you do all kind of shenigans:

```
{{CURRENTYEAR}}-{{padleft:{{#expr:{{CURRENTMONTH1}}-1|2}}-{{CURRENTDAY2}}
{{#time: Y-m-d | now -1 months }}
```

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks!